# How to set the OnClientClick value - syntax?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, onclientclick

ASP.NET coding in VB.NET -- web application.
I am asking a few questions about the "proper way" to set the OnClientClick phrase in the aspx button declaration.

Option 1: **leading with 'javascript:' and surrounding the js in {...}**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"  SkinID="cmdButton" style="margin-left: 2em;"
   CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" 
   OnClientClick = "javascript:{(!confirm('Do you want to delete this record?'); return false;}"
```

Option 2:  **Not leading with 'javascript:' and NOT surrounding the js in {...}**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"  SkinID="cmdButton" style="margin-left: 2em;"
   CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" 
   OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Do you want to delete this record?')) return false;"
```

Both options appear to work properly in IE-10, but have not tried other browsers.  So I am curious about the different phrases.

What about the leading of 'javascript:'? -- what affect does this have?

What about the surrounding of the js with {...} -- what affect does this have?

Your comments are welcome -- what is the best way to construct the phrase.

Any other syntax (or style) or suggestions will be welcome.

Thanks, in advance...John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnClientClick` renders into the standard HTML [`onclick`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) attribute, so put whatever works with it.

I.e. - no `javascript` prefix required, no brackets required as well.